# Blender lagging the more I use

Tags: modeling, rendering, eevee-render-engine, gpu

So basically I bought a new computer;

specs;
32 gb ram
core i5 10th gen
1 tb ssd
no Graphic card

I have been using cpu integrated graphic card and it seem to work fine with blender but as I continue to use it. It starts to lag more and more to a point where selecting a single bone lags for 3 or 4 second but when I close it and open it again seems to work fine but than again it starts to slow down again.

Is it because I don't have graphic card?